# how come ![] is not true?

Tags: javascript

Was just playing around with nodejs and chrome's console when I tested this:

```
[] == true // false
![] == true // false
!![] == true // true
```

How come? Isn't it wrong?

Comment: This is why you don't use implicit unless needed.

Comment: @ColeJohnson—considering the `!` operator converts the LHS to boolean and the RHS is already boolean, the results will be identical. And for the second two, the two algorithms ([Abstract Equality](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) and [Strict Equality](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6) Comparison Algorithm) do exactly the same steps, so there is zero benefit to using one over the other. There may be good reason to do `[] == 0` and not `[] === 0` since the former may be true or false (depending on the members in the arra), but the later will always be false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):

> #### 11.4.9 Logical NOT Operator ( ! )
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* : **!** *UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *expr* be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. Let *oldValue* be ToBoolean(GetValue(*expr*)).
> 3. If *oldValue* is **true**, return **false**.
> 4. Return **true**.
>
> #### 9.2 ToBoolean
>
> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:
>
> - undefined → false
> - null → false
> - Boolean → The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
> - Number → The result is false if the argument is +0, -0, or NaN; otherwise the result is
>     true.
> - The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero);
>     otherwise the result is true.
> - Object → true

An array is an Object.

Comment: but, weirdly enough, empty objects are neighter true or false D:

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: Empty objects are always `true` when evaluated as a Boolean.

Comment: `a = {}; a == true; a == false;` both comparisons returned false in my console...

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: The `==` operator does not cast its operands to boolean values

Comment: @hugo_leonardo just as am not i am says: `!` takes the boolean value (as per 2nd bullet point of 11.4.9). `==` does not do such a thing (see section 11.9.3).

Comment: @amnotiam I guess this explains it ~ so the only one doing the casting is the `!` operator. Thank you (:

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: Study the *Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm* http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3 You'll see that when the two operands are of different types, the conversion is almost always a *toNumber* conversion. An Object gets a *toPrimitive* conversion. In the case of an Array, I believe it first gets *toString*, followed by the *toNumber*. An empty array is therefore converted to `""`, then to `0`. A boolean gets converted *toNumber*, so `false` is `0`. `0 == 0`

Comment: ...yes, the `!` takes it straight to Boolean, which is `true`, but then negated to `false`, so `false == false`.

Comment: @amnotiam— in the first example, the RHS is convereted using *toNumber* but the LHS is an object, so it uses *toPrimitive*, which will be to an empty string so it becomes `'' == 1` which evaluates to false. Note that `[1] == true` returns true as it's converted to `'1' == 1`.

Comment: @RobG: Right, I wasn't differentiating between an Object and an Array. I was just showing that in the case of an empty Array object, it's converted toString `""`, then ultimately toNumber as the conversions continue.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with how the browser handles implicit conversions in JS.

---

As `[]` is an empty array, it evaluates to `false`:

```
[] == true
false == true
```

---

However, `not`ing it, will turn the object into a boolean with a value of `false`:

```
![] == true
false == true
```

However, `boolean([])` will return `true`.

---

However, `not`ing that, will turn it into a boolean with the value of `!false`:

```
!![] == true
!false == true
true == true
```

---

This is why implicit conversions arn't recomended unless needed:

```
"1" == true
true == true

"1" === true
false
```

Comment: it's the same on node.js (edit: well, off course its the same engine. but it's the same on IE's console too)

Comment: @zneak that was a mistake, fixed

Comment: `Boolean([])` -> true, try it.

Comment: An empty array does not evaluate to false: Boolean([]) // true

Comment: but if `Boolean([])` evaluates to true (I expected that too, because it's an object), how come `[] == true` evaluates to false?

Comment: @hugo_leonardo, because implicit casts and explicit casts are not the same. Welcome to Javascript, where casts are not isomorphic.

Comment: Wow, that's confusing. `[] == false` evaluates to true, but `[] || 1` evaluates to `[]`. Sometimes I just don't get javascript...

Comment: @FatalError: There's no way around the fact that the `==` algorithm is a little complex. The first thing to always remember is that `==` is not doing a Boolean evaluation of its operands. When people assume that, it becomes understandably confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`[] == true` is false because `[]` is not equal to `true`, just like `"some string"` is also not equal to `true`.

`![] == true` is false because `[]` *evaluates* to a true value when used in a conditional statement:

```
if([]) console.log('[]');
if(![]) console.log('![]');
// the result will be '[]' because [] will evaluate to true
// in a conditional even though it doesn't equal true
```

Another thing that may help you to think about it is `![] == false` will be `true`.

`!![] == true` is true because `!!` converts anything to a true or false value based on whether it would be true or false in a conditional statement.  So `if(obj)` and `if(!!obj)` will always have the same result.

Comment: I personally use the terms "equal" for `==` and "identical" for `===`, when a distinction between the two is important. Just my 2 cents.